# How to change VirtualBox default VM location in command line

Tags: command-line, virtualbox

The default location is `~/VirtualBox\ VMS`. How can I change it in command line? (GUI is not an option)?

Comment: Would you consider making  `~/VirtualBox\ VMs` a symlink to another directory an option ?

Comment: @Serg, I considered it thanks, reconfiguring the location would be preferable

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is a global VirtualBox property, and can be set with the following command:

```
vboxmanage setproperty machinefolder /path/to/directory/
```

Be aware that this will not move already created VMs, it will affect only VMs which are created after the `machinefolder` property has been set.

Comment: This worked, thanks, this is what I was looking for

Comment: use `vboxmanage list systemproperties | grep folder` to find out the current settings resp. to verify.